# Adding tap device to bridge causes DNS to fail (sometimes)

Tags: networking, dns, network-bridge, tunnel

I am on Ubuntu xenial (16.04 LTS), since I use virtualization, I decided to make a bridged network.

I created the bridge in `/etc/network/interfaces` like so:

```
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports    eth0
  bridge_stp      off
  bridge_maxwait  0
  bridge_fd       0
```

and Internet works just fine before I create a tap device. When I add a tap device for the VM like this:

```
$ user=anyone
$ dev=tap0
$ ip tuntap add $dev mode tap user $usr
$ ip link set $dev up
$ ip link set $dev master br0
```

I can use the tap device to access the Internet without problems from my virtualized guest and **sometimes**, I still have normal Internet access from my host (i.e. DNS is working).

However more often than not, the DNS fails on my host system (I tested by pinging remote hosts with their IP and it worked, with their name it would fail). Everything is fine again on my host system as soon as I remove the tap device.

I do not think these are external network issues, since I had very much the same setup on Fedora, and it worked flawlessly. And to be clear, whether I start the VM or not makes no difference, as soon as the tap comes live I can lose my DNS on the host, and as soon as I remove the tap device it works again.

I can't find anything useful in `dmesg`, `syslog` or `ip route` to help me out. So I am asking here, has anyone an idea what is wrong?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it.
The problem is that the bridge device uses the lowest mac address number of its children as its own by default.
Since the mac addresses for the tap device are more or less random, it sometimes changes the mac of the bridge, and sometimes it does not.
The random MAC is blocked by the DNS in my network.

Luckily, if you assign a MAC to your bridge it will keep it. So I need to add a permanent mac address to the bridge like this

```
ip link set br0 address {MAC-ADDRESS}
```

or to have it at boot I can add *post-up* line to `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
iface br0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports    eth0
  .
  .
  .
  post-up ip link set br0 address {MAC-ADDRESS}
```

For further information see http://backreference.org/2010/07/28/linux-bridge-mac-addresses-and-dynamic-ports/